# Best practice for object modeling when migrating from fluent NHibernate to Mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, fluent-nhibernate, mongorepository

We are currently in the mix of migrating from Fluent NHibernate to MongoDB.  I was curious what might be the best way to go about modeling my objects.  For the most part I wanted to leave them alone, but that may not be possible.  For example I have these two classes:

```
public class Config
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public Filter Filter { get; set; }
}

public class Filter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I understand I have to go with using Guid/string for Id when it comes to MongoDB.  That's no problem.  I have AutoMapper changing that over for me when I migrate the data.  My concern is the data model.  Clearly when I store a Config as a document in MongoDB, I don't want to store the full Filter object along with it, because there is a one-to-many relation there.  Storing that Filter with it would store redundant data.  Is there way via MongoDB mapping to say store the Filter Id only instead of the whole object?  Using Fluent NHibernate I'm able to get this to map properly using those objects above.  I'm hoping I'm just missing something.

EDIT:
I should mention that an obvious solution would be to adjust the Config class like:

```
public class Config : Entity
{
    private string _filterId;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public string FilterId
    {
        get
        {
            if (Filter == null)
                return null;

            _filterId = Filter.Id;
            return _filterId;
        }
        set { _filterId = value; }
    }

    public Filter Filter
    {
        get
        {
            // return code to grab Filter by _filterId from mongo
        }
    }
}
```

However that feels dirty and inelegant to me.  Is there something better?

Comment: Is your domain highly relational? A document database may not be the right solution for you ...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Nope.  Just a couple relational things here and there, but nothing intense.